# "Global variable" in multiple functions

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to collect data with a global variable, without returning the variable

```
def collect_result(result):    
    is_global = "Res_collected" in globals()
    if is_global == False: 
        global Res_collected
        Res_collected = []
    elif is_global == True:
        Res_collected.append(result)
    return
```

How can I use or call this variable in another function?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: The variable is global *and* not even guaranteed to be initialised? That's… a lot of wrong.

Comment: I'm agree with the previous comment of @quamrana even I answered the question.

Comment: ok thanks, I understood that I should avoid using global variables ^^, I did not want to saturate the script with many variables that return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special in order to *read* the value of a global variable inside another function, you can just refer to it by name, so `print(Res_collected)`, for example.

If you want to *write* to the global variable, you would do that in the same way you're already doing it in your `collect_result` function, by using the `global` keyword. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp) is a decent introductory tutorial.

As others have already pointed out, it's generally not a good idea to use global variables. A better alternative is to pass your collection of results as a parameter to whatever functions are going to use them. That way it is clear and explicit what data is being read or modified by each function.

Global variables can hide important clues about what data is being used, where and how, which makes the code harder to understand, and can lead to other problems further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *really bad idea* to use `globals` as indicated by @quamrana and @deceze but if you want to try (not for production please), I suppose the code below should work:

```
>>> globals().setdefault('Res_collected', []).append(res)
```